# Why my views get misplaced when saving or closing my storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, constraints

Recently I am facing a irritating problem. Whenever my storyboard is manipulated by saving/closing xcode, version control systems or closing the storyboard file, my uiviews get misplaced.

The constraints are right, the app runs fine. I just don't want to see the warnings. It`s irritating :)

What can I be doing wrong?

[image: Misplaced views]

Comment: When you click on the ⚠️ (substitute o for !) icon what option do you choose? You should be able to fix it by selecting "update" > "fix misplacement", as it will make the constraints match your canvas...

Comment: I know how to make the warnings disappear temporally, but they come back  whenever I restart xcode or save/close the storyboard file.

Comment: Which option are you choosing to make the warning disappear though? Because if you choose "update" then it should be permanent.

Comment: "fix misplacement". Yeah, it should be permanent, but I`m not getting that behaviour.

Comment: Do you have any stack views? They can cause this. Or it might be the text view; they can be problematic too. I would suggest that you submit this as a bug to Apple, if you can reproduce it.

Comment: The view controllers with the problem haven't stack views or text views. I'll try to submit that to Apple. I think you are right.